# rsLogix 5000, program structure to handle 30 motors simultaneously

Tags: plc, motion

The project is to have 30 linear motors execute commands simultaneously. My question is about the best way to structure the subroutines and if there is a better way to call them.

[Screenshot of the work space and structure of the Control subroutine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzet8.jpg)

As you can see I have the Control subroutine. Each rung of this subroutine calls the other subroutines bellow it in order. The Drive_Status_1 and 2 are called automatically. The other subroutines are only called when an 'examine on' element is true.

This way requires the changing of all the tags for each subroutine for each driver. Having to retype multiple tags and making sure not to miss any has already led to some annoying mistakes and I can only imagine it will get worse with 30 drives. Is there a better way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are doing fine. Many ways to skin a cat.
Looks like your using a 1756-L82E, this processor has plenty of power to do what your asking.  I just did a bottle filler/conveyor control project that is using 35 different drives.  We're controlling them all via Ethernet i/P, I'm not even using a managed switch and we have no problems.  They are all running at the same time.  I rarely separate drives into subroutines, this example of 35 drives are all being controlled within one subroutine.
I do how ever limit the setup/parameter data within the logic.  I try to keep the logic as simple as possible.  Config your drive then only use the necessary parameters within the logic.
Cmd Examples: fwd/Rev, start/stop, fault reset, and speed cmd.
Feedback Examples: Active, Faulted

Below is link to an example of a bare bones drive control scheme.
[Drive logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PYVw.png)

Comment: I'd like to clarify my answer concerning using subroutines.  We use subroutines to group items, in this case motor/drive control, into process related groups.  I try to think of the people who come in later and have to decipher our logic.  In the example i used above, we have a Task Labeled "Conveyors" and within that task is 7 subroutines that group the motors by stages of the process.  Depal conveyors, Rinser Combiner, Infeed, Discharge, Accumulation, labeler Combiner and Labeler Discharge.